# Raspberry Pi 2 NEON instruction set, vector report generation?

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, software-compilation, gcc

Lately I have been trying to generate a vector report of an OpenCV project implemented on the raspberry pi 2 model B, but for some reason there is no output. The same algorithm produces vector report when running on host PC. OpenCV is compiled with the relevant flags, and the CMakeLists.txt is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project( myProject )
add_subdirectory( src  )
include_directories( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/headers"  )
link_directories ( "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src" )
SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/cmake/ )
SET (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O3 -Wall -std=c++11 -mcpu=native -march=native -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=hard -fopenmp -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2")
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
add_executable( myProject main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( myProject src)
target_link_libraries( myProject ${OpenCV_LIBS} )
```

I am compiling with gcc 4.9.2 and the output for

```
gcc -mcpu=native -march=native -Q --help=target
```

gives:

```
The following options are target specific:

-mabi=                                aapcs-linux
-mabort-on-noreturn                   [disabled]
-mandroid                             [disabled]
-mapcs                                [disabled]
-mapcs-float                          [disabled]
-mapcs-frame                          [disabled]
-mapcs-reentrant                      [disabled]
-mapcs-stack-check                    [disabled]
-march=                               armv7ve
-marm                                 [enabled]
-mbig-endian                          [disabled]
-mbionic                              [disabled]
-mcallee-super-interworking           [disabled]
-mcaller-super-interworking           [disabled]
-mcpu=                                cortex-a7
-mfix-cortex-m3-ldrd                  [enabled]
-mfloat-abi=                          hard
-mfp16-format=                        none
-mfpu=                                vfp
-mglibc                               [enabled]
-mhard-float                
-mlittle-endian                       [enabled]
-mlong-calls                          [disabled]
-mlra                                 [enabled]
-mneon-for-64bits                     [disabled]
-mnew-generic-costs                   [disabled]
-mold-rtx-costs                       [disabled]
-mpic-data-is-text-relative           [enabled]
-mpic-register=             
-mpoke-function-name                  [disabled]
-mrestrict-it                         [enabled]
-msched-prolog                        [enabled]
-msingle-pic-base                     [disabled]
-mslow-flash-data                     [disabled]
-msoft-float                
-mstructure-size-boundary=            0x20
-mthumb                               [disabled]
-mthumb-interwork                     [enabled]
-mtls-dialect=                        gnu
-mtp=                                 auto
-mtpcs-frame                          [disabled]
-mtpcs-leaf-frame                     [disabled]
-mtune=                               [default]
-muclibc                              [disabled]
-munaligned-access                    [enabled]
-mvectorize-with-neon-double          [disabled]
-mvectorize-with-neon-quad            [enabled]
-mword-relocations                    [disabled]
-mwords-little-endian                 [disabled]
```

I am assuming there is auto-vectorization functionality with -O3 and there are no specific code manipulations required in order to achieve SIMD parallelism with NEON instruction set (Please correct me if I am wrong). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had posted the same question on the Raspberry Pi forums and all thanks to the user: Paeryn, for the answer. I am re-posting his answer here :

With the latest GCC compilers the `-ftree-vectorizer-verbose` option is depreciated in favour of `-fopt-info-vec`. The `-fopt-info` flag can have several categories added:

- `-ipa` : intra-procedural optimizations
- `-loop` : loop optimizations
- `-vec` : vector optimizations
- `-inline` : inline optimizations
- `-all` : all of the above

See `man gcc` for further details.